# Google Analytics API: which pages triggered custom event?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to use the Google Analytics Reporting API to see at which pagepath the event was triggered. Does anybody know how this is possibel?

In order to integrate it in my current analysis it would be perfekt if this could by done using the segements.

In the analytics interface you can do it by adding the pagepath as a secondary dimension. This procedure I cannot use if I work with sequences though. However, to me it shows, that Google is saving the attribute somewhere.

Thank you for your help

Cheers
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can set opt_label, is the parameter where you can send the page (the other parameters not shown in my example **value** is numerical and **non-interaction** is bool), next is a small example how you can do it

anchor:

```
<a onclick="function () {TriggerEventTrack("In_Cart", "Spicy Food") return false;}" href="#"></a>
```

script:

```
function TriggerEventTrack(category, action, opt_label)

    {
    if (category == undefined !! action == undefined) return;

    if (opt_label == undefined)
    {
    opt_value = window.location.href;
    }
    ...
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, opt_label]
}
```

But in my opinion this is not the correct approach, you can find easy on the page what events were triggered but not the other way around:

In Analytic go **Behavior -> Events -> Pages** -> select pages and you will see some nice reports or you can create your own custom reports.